# How to install acunetix?

Tags: software-installation

[acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/) is a tool that is used to check for web vulnerability. I can't find the Linux version for it anywhere. Is is possible to install it on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5):

Acunetix is available only for Windows Platform. You can try your luck by installing it using [playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html).

But there are other alternatives to Acunetix called **Nikto**. To install **Nikto**, open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install nikto
```

Comment: I installed this. But How can i access this software. I searched in ubuntu installed software. but its not found there

Comment: Gowri, How did you install it? Using Playonlinux?

Comment: Are you talking about Nikto? Nikto is a command-line tool. Open terminal and type nikto.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, Acunetix has released a version for Linux too, see:

https://www.acunetix.com/blog/news/acunetix-vulnerability-scanner-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Acunetix doesnt support Linux Platform. You can use alternatives with [WPScan](https://wpscan.org/).

Comment: Hi Anonymous and welcome to askubuntu! Please add links in future posts, when referring other sites . Further WPScan only scans WordPress webpages for vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try luck installing Acunetix with WINE, but rather than that I suggest to choose one of alternatives available for Linux.

Complete **Acunetix alternatives list** is available here: 
https://alternativeto.net/software/acunetix/?platform=linux